# how to position a decorator panel in gwt

Tags: gwt, panel, decorator, alignment

i was wondering on how to position a decorator panel that wraps around a table. i made a flextable and used the function 'setStyleName' that links to another css file. in the css file, i used absolute positioning with .position as the selector

```
.position
{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;

}
```

however, every time i used the command position:absolute, the flextable will move but the decorator panel (the blue line) doesn't. it just becomes a blue dot. its probably wrapping around something that is 1px by 1px or something. help would be greatly appreciated as ive been super stuck. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set position:absolute for the decorator panel instead of the table.

I don't know what are you to achieve, but maybe you should use "float: right" instead (if you want the panel to stick to the right side of the parent element)

Comment: I've been trying to reposition it inside another table. However, if I ever add 'setStyleName' to the decorator panel, the blue line disappears. Do you know how to fix this? I'm still really stuck = ( Thanks.

Comment: I think you should paste some more code because I don't really know what is the issue with that parent table.